# How to type a function above an arrow like this?

Tags: symbols, mathjax

Can you please tell how to type the function `$f ,g$` above the arrows in the sequence  `$0\to C\to D\to E\to$` like it is in the following image? :[image]

I shall be really grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `\xrightarrow`, as in the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$0 \to C \xrightarrow{f} D \xrightarrow{g} E \to 0$

\end{document}
```

[image: Short exact sequence]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tikz-cd` with the `cramped` option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd, amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
A \emph{short exact sequence of complexes} is a sequence of complexes
\begin{tikzcd}[cramped, column sep=4mm]
0\arrow[r]&C\arrow[r, "f"]&D\arrow[r, "g"]&E\arrow[r]&0
\end{tikzcd} such that for all $i$,
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Standard LaTeX offers the command `\stackrel{..}{..}` for this purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$0\to C\stackrel{f}{\to} D\stackrel{g}{\to} E\to0$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to write a function above an arrow, e.g. with `\overset{}{}`, `\xrightarrow{}` or `\xleftarrow{}`, `\stackrel{}{}`, ...

---

##### Via `\overset{}{}`

```
\documentclass{article}
   \begin{document}
      $0 \rightarrow C \overset{f}{\rightarrow} D \overset{g}{\rightarrow} E \rightarrow 0$
   \end{document}
```

[image: via overset]

##### Via `\xrightarrow{}`

```
\documentclass{article}
   \begin{document}
      $0 \rightarrow C \xrightarrow{f} D \xrightarrow{g} E \rightarrow 0$
   \end{document}
```

[image: via xarrow]

##### Via `\stackrel{}{}`

```
\documentclass{article}
   \begin{document}
      $0 \rightarrow C \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} D \stackrel{g}{\rightarrow} E \rightarrow 0$
   \end{document}
```

[image: via stackrel]

##### Via Matrix

```
\documentclass{article}
   \begin{document}
      $0 \rightarrow C ~\begin{matrix} f\\ \rightarrow\\ ~\end{matrix}~ D ~\begin{matrix} g\\ \rightarrow\\ ~\end{matrix}~ E \rightarrow 0$
   \end{document}
```

[image: via matrix]

...